# How to keep cloned markup in sync

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have a `directive` can have 1 to n `controllers` inside it:

```
<my-directive>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ info.name }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myController2">
    {{ moreInfo.name }}
  </div>
</my-directive>
```

And I programmatically duplicate this markup so that there are now two identical views that reference the same `controller` ids:

```
<my-directive>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ info.name }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myController2">
    {{ moreInfo.name }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ info.name }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myController2">
    {{ moreInfo.name }}
  </div>
</my-directive>
```

Is it possible for the cloned `controllers` to reference the same `scope`? Or is there another way to duplicate the markup without instantiating a new instance of the `controller`?

**I know I can use a `service` to sync data between them**, but since this is happening programmatically, I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: Is there a reason not to declare the controller outside your directive?

Comment: In my particular case, it is a `directive` that can have 1 to n number of "panels". I've simplified it for the question, but the markup would actually have multiple `divs` that each have their own `controller`.

Comment: Why do these child divs have to declare controllers (which create new scope)? Can they declare directives that share a scope?

Comment: The use of this is like a tabs directive, where you can put 1 to n items inside. So would there need to be a directive for each item (i.e. directive1, directive2...directive10)?

Comment: Could you describe in greater depth what your use case is? (what you are trying to do does not feel right, though technically could be accomplished)

Comment: Sure! I'm creating a `directive` that has infinitely swipeable panels, similar to the windows phone ui. Each of the `divs` represents a panel and I duplicate the group and add them before and after the original panels to provide a buffer (e.g. ['1']['2'][1][2]['1']['2'] where ['1'] is the copied panel). When you arrive on a copied panel, I redirect to the original. But if the copied panel does not reference the same object, the data can get out of sync. Does this help?

Comment: At the end of the day, ng-controller is a directive, useful for lots of things but often overused (and oversized). *Custom* directives give you additional flexibility for creating discrete parts in an application that interact with one with specific rules (e.g. dependencies on one another, isolate scope, etc.) It *sounds* like you'd want to use directives here, but it does still seem as if the problem is not clearly defined.

Comment: It also sounds as if you should be using a service for data sharing, and I don't understand why you've ruled it out.

Comment: I haven't ruled out services, I was just looking for alternatives. Since there could be many distinct controllers within this directive, I wanted to avoid using a service because I would have to create one for every controller. This felt wrong to me because the service would only exist to handle the problem imposed by the directive. I would rather have the directive solve its own problem. It might not be possible with how it is set up, but I was hoping for the directive to be robust enough to handle whatever I put in it.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I still can't understand what you're trying to do. Keep at it, read the Angular docs/blog posts/etc, and if you continue to get stuck try asking some questions that either a) are  more bite-sized or b) include more example code or a Fiddle/Plunk that demonstrates what you've tried

Comment: @marck I posted a new question that explains what I am trying to accomplish in much more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399860/windows-phone-panorama-with-angularjs I hope this helps with understanding my particular problem. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the controller to the directive, it's the same function anyways

```
<my-directive>
  <div>
    {{ info.name }}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ info.name }}
  </div>
</my-directive>
```

Comment: also why not use a scope data with ng-repeat?  cloning seems a bit funny here as you cannot remanipulate the data again.

Comment: What if there can be multiple `divs` inside the directive that each use their own controller, and all of the `divs` get cloned?

Comment: you wanna think about why you need a different controller (function literally) for every div.  are they all doing the same repetitive thing?  is it just the data that is different between them? At the end, angularjs is still javascript and that's programming so you wanna think of the framework from a programmer's logic.

Comment: The concept is like tabs, where the items within the directive will be different functions. E.g. Account, Orders, Shipments, etc. Because of this, I want to allow for controllers on each item as necessary so there isn't one very large controller for a group of somewhat related tasks.

Comment: i guess you can have one parent scope for all of them and broadcast or pass whatever message or data you need to, and still have child controllers for every directive.