# Windows Phone Panorama with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to replicate the Windows Phone Ui in an AngularJS app. Here is an [example](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/gallery/features/1295629/designing-windows-phone-8/177979) of what a Windows Phone Ui looks like.

[image: Windows Phone Ui]

### Infinite Swipe

One interesting thing about it is the panels are infinitely swipe-able. You can keep swiping and end up back at the first panel.

To achieve the infinite swipe, I duplicate the first and last panels and add them before and after the original panels like this:

[image: Copied Panels]

If you swipe to a copied panel (like "3" or "1"):

[image: Swipe to copied panel]

you are redirected to the real panel immediately after the swipe finishes. This happens without the user even knowing because there is no animation.

[image: Redirect to actual panel]

### Problem

The problem is that the panels can have `ng-controller`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-model`, or any number of things that create scope within them. When I duplicate the markup a new scope is created that starts out identical to the original but does not stay in sync. How do I keep the panel data in sync?

OR, is there another way to achieve this that does not involve duplicating markup?

### Ideas

1. One idea I had was moving the DOM elements around instead of duplicating. I noticed significant lag with this strategy and if there are only two panels, this breaks down because the non-selected panel either needs to go before the current panel or after.*This was not acceptable to me because of the perceived performance loss*
2. Another option is delaying the movement of the panel contents until after the swipe is completed. You would still see the panel titles, but the content would be invisible until you finish swiping. Then, I can determine which panel is now current and animate it coming in from the proper direction (depending on the direction of the swipe).
3. A third option is using blank panels with a loading spinner as the "duplicated" or buffer panels. If you swipe to a panel that is not one of the originals, you would see a flash of the loading spinner until you are moved to the actual panel.

None of these options are ideal, so I'm looking for other ideas. But if there aren't any good options, #2 seems like the best plan to me.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial for a photo slider using ngTouch: http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-angularjs-photo-slider-pt-2-ngtouch/ View the demo with element inspector open in your browser dev tools. Notice that the elements aren't reordered or duplicated in the DOM. Only the position is shifted in and out of the visible frame via CSS positioning.

Comment: In other words, the panels don't have to exist in a stacked horizontal row as you've shown in your question. They just need to be somewhere off canvas, but you can use animation to have panels slide in from the left & right to make it seem as if they were in a line off screen.

Comment: This is kind of like idea #2, but I think it can be improved in a few ways. First, the current panel can move according to you touch (e.g. if you touch and drag 20px to the left, the panel would move 20px left). Then when you pass a threshold and release, it would essentially do the same thing - figure out what panel is next and which direction it should come from, then animate it entering in. The downside of this is you don't see the content until after you finish swiping, but this might just be a necessary compromise.

Comment: My point in linking the tutorial was to demonstrate the concept - you could implement something similar with whatever refinements you'd like. I'm not seeing why you wouldn't see the content until the swipe is completed. There's no reason it couldn't remain on the panel as it animates.

Comment: show the code you already have for this. it's too vague and hard to visualize at the moment

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a question about sharing state between different instances of a controller (the 'real' 1 panel and the 'fake' "1" panel) and it has been asked before....

[I have two divs with the same ng-controller in AngularJS, how can I make them share information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170464/i-have-two-divs-with-the-same-ng-controller-in-angularjs-how-can-i-make-them-sh)

I like the answer suggesting a service to share state between instances...

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.service('myservice', function(){
    this.data = "Hi, I'm shared"
});

app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', 'myservice', function ($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.setData = function(newData){myservice.data = newData};
    $scope.getData = function(){return myservice.data};
}]);
```

Here is a working fiddle that demonstrates the approach

http://jsfiddle.net/michaeldausmann/WMPv3/#base

Michael